# Wifi can't connect, Ethernet can

Tags: wifi, internet

I can't seem to fix the wifi connection. Even if I restart Elementary, I still have no option about wifi connection.

I can only connect to internet by using Ethernet cable.

[image: a busy cat]

Is there any way to fix it?

I have already installed linux-image-generic-lts-xenial, and have disabled wifi power saving, but the wifi is still not being shown.

I believe I am not the first to have this problem, but I can't seem to find similar question in Elementary forums.

Thank you

Edit:
If this helps you: When I open wifi at system settings, the tab is empty. 
[image]

Can anybody suggest anything else? None of the solutions provided already works.

Edit: So, no one has experienced this kind of problem before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, I had to reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source:

```
sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be that your network manager needs restarted.

Try

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, no change is made if I restart network manager.

Comment: Also, I have already installed linux-image-generic-lts-xenial, but wifi does not show up.

Comment: Is wifi available if your running from a live USB?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't own a live USB. But two days ago Wifi was working just fine. I think after I updated Elementary, it showed problems. Also in Windows Wifi works fine.

Comment: What method did you install elementary?

Comment: I did not install it, I just used **sudo apt-get update** to update my packages.

Comment: I was referring to the whole OS. Generally it's done by creating a Live USB or CD to boot and install from. I was curious whether the wifi was working in the Live environment prior to install.

Comment: Yes, I created a live USB and installed Elementary from that. The wifi was working prior to install.

Answer (score 0):

Considering you mentioned that it worked during the Live CD/Install. I would try disabling Secure Boot via your BIOS or you could also use Mokutil to do so:

`sudo apt install mokutil
sudo mokutil --disable-validation`

It will ask you to create a password that is at least 8 characters long. Next you will need to reboot into Ubuntu and it will ask you to confirm the password that you created. *It might ask for individual letters to be typed in instead of the entire password*

Let me know how it goes!

Comment: I tried that, but EFI variables are not supported on my system.